# Build success but run crash while others run successfully after check ios code from svn alongside cocoapods

Tags: ios, svn, cocoapods, xcode10

I joined a new company last day, they use svn to store code, they even store cocoapods repos in the svn alongside the source code.

They can build and run the code successfully without any modification and without `pod install`

But after I check it out, I can build it successfully , but crashed when run.

The first place crashes is :

```
DDFileLogger *fileLogger = [[DDFileLogger alloc] init]; // File Logger 
fileLogger.rollingFrequency = 60 * 60 * 24; // 24 hour rolling
fileLogger.maximumFileSize = 0;
fileLogger.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 1;
fileLogger.logFileManager.logFilesDiskQuota = 0;
[DDLog addLogger:fileLogger];
_fileLogger = fileLogger;
NSLog(@"%s %@",__func__,fileLogger.logFileManager);
NSLog(@"%s %@",__func__,[fileLogger.logFileManager logsDirectory]);
```

after comment these lines, other places crash. it seems like it will crash at the place where 3rd-party library uses.

Can anybody help? many thanks to you!

I attach the crash logs here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9iqpgph6gqbnpbt/BleLocker%20%202018-11-22%20%E4%B8%8B%E5%8D%885-07.crash?dl=0

Comment: Can you show your crash logs too?

Comment: Did you do a clean & full build? Didn't they put some built code on SVN?

Comment: Yes, I did a full clean and build

Comment: Put a break on all exceptions, so you can trace the code back into BleLocker. Also, check that the issue appears only with this version of iOS?

Comment: It seems only related to Mac. with other's Mac and my iphone, it works fine. the same code

Answer (score 0):

Er, I've found the reason, I evaluated a third-party security tool yesterday that will replace original clang with its own clang.

This clang will crash the app